# Why does function's argument get written to main stack frame and not function stack frame?

Tags: c, gcc, stack, gdb

So I have this piece of C code disassembled in gdb:

```
0x08048474 <main+0>: push ebp
0x08048475 <main+1>: mov ebp,esp
0x08048477 <main+3>: sub esp,0x8
0x0804847a <main+6>: and esp,0xfffffff0
0x0804847d <main+9>: mov eax,0x0
0x08048482 <main+14>: sub esp,eax
0x08048484 <main+16>: cmp DWORD PTR [ebp+8],0x1
0x08048488 <main+20>: jg 0x80484ab <main+55>
0x0804848a <main+22>: mov eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
0x0804848d <main+25>: mov eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
0x0804848f <main+27>: mov DWORD PTR [esp+4],eax
0x08048493 <main+31>: mov DWORD PTR [esp],0x80485e5
0x0804849a <main+38>: call 0x804831c <printf@plt>
0x0804849f <main+43>: mov DWORD PTR [esp],0x0
0x080484a6 <main+50>: call 0x804833c <exit@plt>
0x080484ab <main+55>: mov eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
0x080484ae <main+58>: add eax,0x4
0x080484b1 <main+61>: mov eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
0x080484b3 <main+63>: mov DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x080484b6 <main+66>: call 0x8048414 <check_authentication>
0x080484bb <main+71>: test eax,eax
0x080484bd <main+73>: je 0x80484e5 <main+113>
0x080484bf <main+75>: mov DWORD PTR [esp],0x80485fb
0x080484c6 <main+82>: call 0x804831c <printf@plt>
0x080484cb <main+87>: mov DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048619
0x080484d2 <main+94>: call 0x804831c <printf@plt>
0x080484d7 <main+99>: mov DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048630
0x080484de <main+106>: call 0x804831c <printf@plt>
0x080484e3 <main+111>: jmp 0x80484f1 <main+125>
0x080484e5 <main+113>: mov DWORD PTR [esp],0x804864d
0x080484ec <main+120>: call 0x804831c <printf@plt>
0x080484f1 <main+125>: leave
0x080484f2 <main+126>: ret
End of assembler dump.
```

My main question revolves around these lines:

```
0x080484b3 <main+63>: mov DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x080484b6 <main+66>: call 0x8048414 <check_authentication>
```

When I step through esp = 0xbffff7e0 at this point in time. When I step into the check_authentication function esp = 0xbffff7a0. These lines are writing the address for a (char *) that is the argument for check_authentication but they are writing it at 0xbffff7e0 and not within the stack frame of 0xbffff7a0 - 0xbffff7e0. The only rationale I can think of is that stacks are allocated padding when they are created and because this is probably padding the compiler is doing this to save space? Does anyone know if that's the case? Why doesn't it write the address at esp-4 which is actually inside the function's stack frame?

EDIT: Adding memory outputs to help with my poor explanation

Inside main():

```
(gdb) x/4xw $esp
0xbffff7e0: 0xb8000ce0 0x08048510 0xbffff848 0xb7eafebc
```

Inside of check_authentication():

```
(gdb) x/32xw $esp
0xbffff7a0: 0x00000000 0x08049744 0xbffff7b8 0x080482d9
0xbffff7b0: 0xb7f9f729 0xb7fd6ff4 0xbffff7e8 0x00000000
0xbffff7c0: 0xb7fd6ff4 0xbffff880 0xbffff7e8 0xb7fd6ff4
0xbffff7d0: 0xb7ff47b0 0x08048510 0xbffff7e8 0x080484bb
0xbffff7e0: 0xbffff9b7 0x08048510 0xbffff848 0xb7eafebc
```

In main 0xbffff7e0 = 0xe00c00b8

In check_authentication 0xbffff7e0 = 0xb7f9ffbf

The change occurs right before jumping into check_authentication but the change is meant for check_authentication so why is it at 0xbffff7e0 which is where mains() esp points to and not within check_function's stack frame. I'm racking my brain trying to figure this out.

Comment: My assembly sucks, so I might be wrong, but didn't it move the pointer to the CPU register (`eax`) and work on the CPU register's copy of the data at that point? If the data is on the register, you can't really see the valid value when debugging (not by checking the value stored in the RAM, anyway).

Comment: it moves the pointer value that eax points to inoto the memory location that esp points to which is 0xbffff7e0

Comment: On x86, it's alright if a function allocates a larger stack frame than is necessary.  Here, it's using mov to store args into the top n positions of the stack, calling a function, then continuing without doing any pops. It does the same when it calls another function.  This uses fewer instructions because it skips all the popping (or adding 4 or 8 or whatever to esp). From the callee's point of view, the stack is exactly correct; it doesn't care if its caller used pushes or moves.

Comment: Thanks @MarkPlotnick, I figured that it was something to do with saving on instructions.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "allocated stack frames in x86". Stack is a continuous memory area, with SP pointing to the "top of stack" (its lowest address).
The assembly is not storing at some random address, but in `[ESP]`, so it is within the function's stack frame - between the EBP and the current ESP **inclusive**.

---

`PUSH` opcode is defined not unlike the following C statement:

```
*--SP = value;   // decrease pointer first, then store
```

whereas `POP` is

```
value = *SP++;   // take the value pointed to, then increase pointer
```

---

Now in this line just before `CALL check_authentication` the compiler, instead of generating a `PUSH`, `POP` pair, just does the equivalent of

```
*SP = value;
```

Comment: It stores within the current stack frame but it's storing an address meant for the next stack frame.

Comment: SP points to the topmost item. When check_authentication is called that is the first argument to that function.